# Does worker skill increase?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have a resident in my tower with 2/2/2/2 skill across the four job types; will he ever improve or is he just dead weight?  Is there a reason to keep any people with a skill below the maximum of nine?

Comment: If it's anything like Tiny Tower, and it appears to mostly be just a reskin of it, then no they never gain skill. Haven't played it though.

Answer (score 5):

**He is just dead weight...** though he can still work for you.   As of right now, there is no way to increase their skill.

I recommend trying to get close to 9s skill for maximum profit. [*Evict the skill-less bitzens until you find one worthy!*]

Comment: Less skilled bitizens are exercises in compromise :)  ... whether you should hire a 0-8 bitizen NOW until a 9 comes, or WAIT and leave the job open and not making money.

Answer (score 0):

The second question is all about whether you should hire a 0-8 bitizen NOW until a 9 comes, or WAIT and leave the job open and not making money.

The answer depends how fast that job orders and sells vs. how soon a 9 will likely arrive.

Consider the following scenario:

- it's the third product of the floor, and it says it takes 3 hours to stock the product.
- all your residences are full, you're still raising money to build a residential floor, and the last floor you built took 2 hours!
- the unemployed bitizen is a 7.

If you play like I do, you'll hire the 7.  Grab the opportunity now, despite the 28% difference in performance.